# how to addSubLayer to layer in Swift UIView class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I created a FirstView class as a UIView class and added a container to add some layers, for example salamLogo, and addSub layer in initializeViews() func

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class FirstView: UIView {
    var container: UIView {
        let x = CGFloat(0.0),
        y = CGFloat(0.0),
        w = CGFloat(screenWidth),
        h = CGFloat(screenHeight - statusBarHeight)
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h))
        view.background(color: UIColor.red)
        return view
    }

    var salamLogo: CALayer {
        let layer = CALayer()
        let view = UIImage(named: "sibdiet_logo")?.cgImage
        let x = CGFloat(screenWidth / 2 - 72.0),
        y = CGFloat(20.0),
        w = CGFloat(160.0),
        h = CGFloat(160.0)
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
        layer.contents = view
        layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
        return layer
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeViews()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeViews()
    }
    private func initializeViews(){
        container.layer.addSublayer(salamLogo)
        addSubview(container)
    }

}
```

in ViewController add object from FirstView class and addSubView

```
import UIKit

var screenHeight: CGFloat =  UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let screenWidth: CGFloat =  UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var firstView:  FirstView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        screenHeight = screenHeight == 812 ? 788 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height

        firstView = FirstView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: statusBarHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight ))
        self.view.addSubview(firstView)

    }
}
```

in simulator show a red frame but don't show salamLogo layer, or any layer into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding layers is very similar as adding subviews:

```
layer.addSublayer(salamLogo)
```

But in your case may be better to work with subviews? I do not see any purpose of using layers here. You can make `salamLogo` as regular `UIImageView`

====== EDIT =====

Back to your solution. There is a problem in your code. Every time you call `container`  or `salamLogo` you will create new UIView and new CALayer. To keep only one instance you should do:

```
    lazy var container: UIView = {
        let x = CGFloat(0.0),
        y = CGFloat(0.0),
        w = CGFloat(screenWidth),
        h = CGFloat(screenHeight - statusBarHeight)
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h))
        view.background(color: UIColor.red)
        return view
    }()

    lazy var salamLogo: CALayer = {
        let layer = CALayer()
        let view = UIImage(named: "sibdiet_logo")?.cgImage
        let x = CGFloat(screenWidth / 2 - 72.0),
        y = CGFloat(20.0),
        w = CGFloat(160.0),
        h = CGFloat(160.0)
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
        layer.contents = view
        layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
        return layer
    }()
```

Comment: I have a lot of layers like shapes and gradients that I want to add to the container

Comment: remove container and fix problem